# Pattern matching without the match keyword

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

In her article [When OO and FP meet: returning the same type](http://blog.jessitron.com/2014/02/when-oo-and-fp-meet-mytype-problem.html), @Jessitron gives this example code (with minor differences):

```
object Policy {
   def adjust[P <: Policy](p: P, d: Discount): P = {
     case ap: AutoPolicy => new AutoPolicy
     case lp: LifePolicy => new LifePolicy
     // ... etc
   }
}
```

On what value is the pattern matching being applied? I am confused by the lack of a `match` keyword.

Comment: I don't think that code compiles... could be a bug in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code wouldn't be compilable without the `match` keyword like below:

```
def adjust[P <: Policy](p: P, d: Discount) = p match {
  case ap: AutoPolicy => new AutoPolicy
  case lp: LifePolicy => new LifePolicy
}
```

If the intention were to define a `PartialFunction` (which seems unlikely), it would have had a different signature:

```
def adjust[P <: Policy](p: P, d: Discount): PartialFunction[P, _] = {
  case ap: AutoPolicy => new AutoPolicy
  case lp: LifePolicy => new LifePolicy
  // ...
}
```